# Ожидание наполнения массива в другом потоке

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

У меня есть глобальный массив и 2 события `event`. На момент запуска программы события вызываются параллельно. В одном событии массив заполняется, а в другом используется. Необходимо во втором событие как-то реализовать ожидание того, пока массив заполнится из другого события.

Я это делаю через while

```
while(array.Count < 60) {}
```

Можно ли как-нибудь более лаконично реализовать это?

Аналогично пример, если я в одном потоке создаю переменную и значение должен получить в каком-либо событии и затем её инициализировать. Т.е. мне нужно в потоке включить режим ожидания, пока вызовется событие и я получу значение.

Comment: У массива нет свойства Count. Какая коллекция на самом деле используется? Она потокобезопасная?

Comment: Запускайте второе событие из первого, когда все данные уже готовы.

Comment: Или используйте инструменты сиезронизации потоков, `Lock` или `ManualResetEvent` или что то подобное

Comment: При работе с потоками такая задача решается мьютексами.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов мьютекс таки будет перебор, имхо. Тут же не нужна кросс-процесс синзронизация.

Comment: @tym32167 А если я подключаюсь к двум потокам на сервере, откуда поступают разные данные. Я ведь не могу вызвать одно событие из другого, они поступают параллельно. 
Решение которое я вижу - подключиться вначале к одному потоку, он соберет все данные и потом подключиться к другому потоку и дальше они будут работать вместе уже.

Comment: я не знаю, что значит потоки на сервере, но если вы можете избежать необходимости синхронизации потоков и это вас устроит и по скорости работы и по всему, то я рекомендую это сделать. Если вам подходит не параллельная, но последовательная обработка ваших функций, я бы так и сделал. Меньше синзронизации = меньше проблем с синхронизацией.